# Manually set figure and table labels while compiling

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, appendices, apa-style

I would like to manually set certain figure and table labels in LaTeX2e.

I imagine the process to go something like:

latex -> edit .aux file (?) to revise some labels -> pdf

The problem: the [apa6e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6e) package mislabels figures in certain cases when using an appendix (see example below). I would like to change Figure A1, etc., throughout the body to Figure 1, preferably as a batch search-and-replace, while still retaining the automatic labelling for the rest of the document.

Example: The following code --

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\title{}
\author{}
\shorttitle{}
\authornote{}
\begin{document}

This figure, in the body, should reference as Figure~1, not
Figure~\ref{bodyfigure}.

\begin{table*}
\caption{Body table.}
\end{table*}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Body figure.}
\label{bodyfigure}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\section{}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Appendix Table.}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

-- produces `Figure A1` rather than `Figure 1`.

I would like to either (1) find a way to manually set labels before compiling the PDF, or (2) find a work-around for apa6e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I just have found out this is IMHO clearly a bug within the apa6e document class. The figure and table counter will be reset & redefined inside both files with extension `.fff` and `.ttt` (which are handled by the endfloat package). This is obviously wrong since the `.fff` file is responsible for figures only and `.ttt` for tables only. (As a result the figure label will be redefined and reset too soon when using your example document.)

So by redefining the internal macro `\apaSIXe@appendixfloats@setup` (which is responsible for the misbehavior) this could be fixed:

```
\documentclass{apa6e}

% Workaround for bug in apa6e document class
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\apaSIXe@appendixfloats@setup}[1]{%
  \efloat@iwrite{fff}{%
    \string\makeatletter\string\apaSIXe@appendixfloats@figure{#1}\string\makeatother}%
  \efloat@iwrite{ttt}{%
    \string\makeatletter\string\apaSIXe@appendixfloats@table{#1}\string\makeatother}%
}
% The following stuff was done by \apaSIXe@appendixfloats@go before.
% I have split this macro into \...@figure and \...@table here:
\newcommand{\apaSIXe@appendixfloats@figure}[1]{%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{#1\arabic{figure}}%
}
\newcommand{\apaSIXe@appendixfloats@table}[1]{%
  \setcounter{table}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{#1\arabic{table}}%
}
\makeatother

\title{}
\author{}
\shorttitle{}
\authornote{}
\begin{document}

This figure, in the body, should reference as Figure~1, not
Figure~\ref{bodyfigure}.

\begin{table}
\caption{Body table.}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Body figure.}
\label{bodyfigure}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\section{}

\begin{table}
\caption{Appendix Table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please do a bug report to the author of the apa6e document class so this bug will be fixed for future versions of apa6e.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer to adjust this in the LaTeX code instead constantly have to hack the `.aux` file after every compilation.

This class changes the `\thefigure` macro which is responsible for the labeling of the `figure`. For some reason it does this not globally but in `\begin{figure}`. You need to change the definition to use simple Arabic numbers again before the caption and the label:

```
\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}%
\caption{Body figure.}
\label{bodyfigure}
\end{figure}
```

This changes both the `\ref` and caption number to `Figure 1`.

Comment: Since the bug in the apa6e document class will not only label the figure wrong, but will give them a wrong counter, too, this workaround seems to be ok for this particular MWE, but is not sufficient in general.